# Xubuntu 16.04 - slow suspend and resume

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I decided to upgrade my 14.04 system to the new LTS stuff. One of the problems I encountered is the following

> I set up the laptop to suspend when I close the lid. When I close the lid it takes about 15 seconds to suspend (vs 2 before). When I open the lid the computer resumes but the network is off for about 10 seconds.

I'm not sure if somebody else has the same problem. It's a fresh install. How can I make the laptop suspend and resume faster?

Comment: I too have found this problem. On 14.04, upon opening the lid the screen was almost instantly on without any problems. Now it takes a long time.

Comment: @VladisGlad: Unfortunately not many people are bothered by this... I found the source, but I don't have a fix yet. Type `systemd-inhibit` in a terminal and see what you get. I have a network manager disabler when suspending (don't know why that's necessary) and the xfce4 power manager is ignored...